# Sub package of maven content package Installation order issue

Tags: maven, java-8, aem, jcr

Sub package of maven content package installation order is not exactly same as whatever mentioned in pom file.
This is happening only in AEM CQ 6.x instance using jdk1.8 java version.
In jdk 1.8 maven content package Installation checks package group alphabetical order. Is there any way to install the sub package is the same order which is mentioned in pom.

```
                <subPackages>
                    <subPackage>
                         <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                         <artifactId>first</artifactId>
                    </subPackage>
                    <subPackage>
                         <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                         <artifactId>second</artifactId>
                    </subPackage>
                </subPackages>
```

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to set the order for content package installation. I would advice you to check your application because there should be absolutely no need for a specific order. It seems you designed your application wrong.

Comment: There is two different custom package has overrides one another in some css files. To avoid that we need sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Sub Packages make a perfect fit for Russian Doll like deployments, where you split up your Blob like CMS App into "Verticals" (using Context Mapping as a strategic Domain-Driven Design pattern).
Each Vertical would be represented as a SubPackage (that brings the Content and the Bundles to the table that makes up the Business Sub-Domain aka Vertical).

This has the Benefit that multiple Teams can work on those Verticals in parallel and each team can just deploy their SubPackage standalone (`mvn install -PautoInstallPackage`) - better isolation and better roundtrip times during development (you just deploy what you changed on your localbox).

You would then need to have a Top Level Content Package or UBER Content Package that includes all Content Packages that represent the Verticals so to be able to install the whole Package into any TEST,QA or PROD Env.

The order SHOULD NOT be of importance as long as they are independent.
At times though, you have dependencies.

you should strive for declaring those dependencies within the DEPENDENT Content Package Project using Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <name>mysubdomain-ui-content</name>
        <finalName>mysubdomain-ui-content-${project.version}</finalName>
        <filterSource>src/main/resources/vault/filter.xml</filterSource>
        <properties>
            <acHandling>merge_preserve</acHandling>
            <description>Content Package that has a dependency on another Content Package that needs to be installed first</description>
            <!-- controls deployment order when installing the myproject-content Package -->
            <!-- As both packages have the same lifecycle, the project.version is the same for both -->
            <dependencies><groupIDOtherPKG>:<artifactIDOtherPackage>:${project.version}</dependencies>  <!-- here goes the magic -->
        </properties>
        <subPackages>
            <subPackage>
```

You would need to set the `<groupIDOtherPKG>:<artifactIDOtherPackage>` to the respective Maven Coordinates of the Package you depend on here (e.g mycompany:my-content-package).

Typically you need this kind of dependency declaration if the other Content Package not only brings Content but also Bundles to the Table, your Content Package in question depends on.

Just keep in mind to not produce cycles.
Even though maven will prevent you from doing this, you should make up your mind in the beginning which Verticals / Content Packages are allowed to depend on others...

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need to install sub packages in a specific order? Does it mean the sub packages have inner dependencies?

Comment: We are trying to install all the project packages into one master package. In that there is one package should be deployment at another last.